# Spiderman and the Cantor's function .

Tags: real-analysis, probability, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, fractals

Well it's an imaginative and soft question so take it as you wish .

Problem : imagine Spider-man walking on the cantor function (see the plot like the side of a building) :

[image: cantor-function]

Now he can throw a line to come faster to the top of the stairs . The problem is the spider-man webs can only solidify on an angle(i.e corner).

Question :

If spiderman have a limitied number of spider-webs which stay only on angle (corner) what is the probability he comes to the top of the stairs on a limited interval of the Cantor's function admitting it's his only means of transport ?

Do you have a strategy ?

I have no attempt because it's a new problem for me but Bernoulli's distribution could be a start  .

Example of path to come on a horizontal line :

[image: Spiderman-path]

The new question is :

> > Finalizing Question :

---

If Spiderman is a point on that curve and have the probability $P=1/2$ to get a rational point $(x_i,y_i)$ on the curve he choose (The Cantor set here) and stop if the point is irrational what's the probability he goes at the top of the devil staircase ($x=y=1$) if he is assimilated to an increasing unknow $x$ starting to $x=0$ and $x_i<x_{i+1}$.In other word what's the probability he diverges (projective geometrical point of view) to $x=y=1$ choosing a number of rational point which is bounded  ?

We can bound it with the Fréchet-Boole's inequality .

To figure it see :

[image: Circle-ford]

Another one and Thomae function

[image: Popcornfunction]

The problem can be reformulate in term of Brownian motion :

[image: Spidermanmotion]

Simplifying question for kids :

If now a kid plays with a
[Soap bubble](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation) and the bubble in a slight wind goes to a staircase what's chance the bubble don't collapse before the end of the next level of the home?

Reference :

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inequalities

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.08407v1.pdf

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2205/2205.01925.pdf

Comment: At the start, the slope is in effect vertical. How does that affect "walking on the Cantor function" and "spider-man webs can only solidify on an angle".  What is a "limited interval of the Cantor function"?

Comment: I guess by 'angle' is meant 'corner' (as these words are the same words in some languages) which would here be the leftmost point of an interval at which the graph runs horizontally. But Erik Satie can better clarify this himself

Comment: @Henry a limited interval is $x\in[0,1]$ for example .Spiderman start on a plateau (need to define that ) of the devil's stairs   otherwise there no possibility . The problem in standart mathematics is if we have a line $f(x)=ax+b$ starting from a point on an interval $[a,b],0<a<b$ which intersect two extrema (one of the point is a maxima on a subinterval) of the Cantor's function how many line we need to come on a plateau sufficiently large .See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LineLinePicking.html

Comment: See also Jarvis march https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

Comment: I don't know if I'd call this a `soft-question`. In my opinion, it's a somewhat squidgy :-) question that needs to nail down what it means, but once it does that, it would seem to have a specific answer.

Comment: @BrianTung See the edit and thanks for the sophisticate English.

Comment: I put here some question : Do the two events "have a consecutive rational point"and "get a irrational point " dependent ? If so does it works like a "dice probabilstic system" (Bernoulli's distribution) ?If so the form of the dice count so does rational number have a "form" which make it dependent ?

Comment: Well now I think it's not a "soft" question since there is potential depth question see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.4141.pdf

Comment: Intruiging idea https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209073/is-the-zero-set-of-brownian-motion-homeomorphic-to-cantor-space

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ulam_problem

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Basic_Examples:_Propagator_of_Free_Particle_and_Harmonic_Oscillator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of this answer and the strategy which come with it  start :

What is the convex hull of the devil staircase taking only extremal point $P_i$ which is bounded ?

In fact if Spiderman (view as a point) have an illimited numbers of webs Jarvis march is sufficient if we admits there is a limited numbers of point in the convex hull .

Now as it's limited we can refine Jarvis march with Chan's algorithm which is more efficient .

There are other strategy but take it as an example for this problem of computational geometry .

Hope you find something clear and give your feedback.

Edit :

In term of probabilities see [Expected number of vertices in a convex hull](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469295/expected-number-of-vertices-in-a-convex-hull)

---

---

---

---

From [here](https://www.mat.uc.cl/%7Egiommi/notas3_escuela.pdf) (p.35) it seems that the probability is equal to $1/2$ is it right ?(false)

See [https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matmj/Demislides.pdf](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematmj/Demislides.pdf) and Mahler question .

Using this paper the answer seems to be $P\simeq 1/3^n$ (false too)

I found an partial answer here [Continued Fraction and Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344894/continued-fraction-and-random-variable)

And here ["Probability" measures on Cantor set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437465/probability-measures-on-cantor-set)

Edit :

If we consider the term "equiprobable" so the answer is $1/2$ see

[Thou shalt not say “at random” in vain:
Bertrand’s paradox exposed](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.07805.pdf)

---

---

See theorem 5.1 Tchernoff bound [here](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elaci/reu02/fourier.pdf)

Comment: See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: https://ahl.centre-mersenne.org/item/10.5802/ahl.44.pdf